# Copy Mac Address into Clipboard help in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, script, batch, mac-address

Given the batch script below.  How would I be able to give me a MAC address with no dashes and add a "D" in front of it?  So when I go and paste, it has a MAC address that starts with a D and there are no dashes?  Possibly even using what I copied to automatically change the computer name with it using newsid?

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /f "tokens=12 delims= " %%a IN ('IPCONFIG /all^|FINDSTR "Physical Address"') DO (
    SET PA=%%a
    IF NOT "%PA%"=="." GOTO Done
)

:Done

ECHO %PA%| CLIP
CLS
ECHO The Physical Address has been copied to the clipboard.
ECHO.
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Comment: I think this page has the relevant info on stripping the dashes. http://www.robvanderwoude.com/bht.php#Strip ..not sure about appending the D.

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo D%PA:-=%|clip` instead.

Note though, that you're getting the last MAC address on your computer which could really be anything. At least on my machine that doesn't correspond to any phsyical interface.

Comment: Thank you that worked!  I only have one NIC on the machines, no wireless or virtual NICs.