# Copy Mac Address of the most recent networking device inserted in my computer! Possible?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch-file, ipconfig, findstr

I borrowed a batch script from another user on this site so that I can copy a Mac address automatically whenever I click it. But I need modifying the script.
Here's the link.

[Copy Mac Address into Clipboard help in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/266664/copy-mac-address-into-clipboard-help-in-windows-7)

I need it to copy only the most recent Mac address that was put in the computer. I can't find a way to do this so I just use the findstr command. I altered the order of each Mac address to show in the ipconfig /all command by unchecking the automatic interface metric option of each adapter and arranging them manually to my liking.

Here's the problem - no matter what I do, when connected to my company's VPN, the VPN adapter's Mac address ALWAYS shows up first. I can't alter it nor do I want to.

My core question is this: Given the batch file in the link, is there a way for the findstr command to skip the VPN's Mac when it shows up first? (When not connected to the VPN the adapter is disabled and shows later in the list.)

If anyone is unclear I'm happy to explain again. (As long as you read fully.) The batch file basing itself on findstr and ipconfig /all is not a must but it works very well when not on the VPN. Also it must  be a script language that works without involving any third party downloads. Thanks!

Comment: If you execute this command what kind of results did you want to get exactly ?
`getmac /NH /FO:CSV`

Comment: Can you execute powershell commands into a batch file ?

Comment: Ok so I just learned that PowerShell scripts are also acceptable. Yay.

Comment: I changed the title to more accurately reflect what I'm aiming to accomplish.

Comment: @Rets86 As far as I know Windows doesn't keep really keep track of "the most recently inserted" network adapter. The order in which Windows lists network-interfaces (real and/or virtual ones) is quite random and may even change between 2 attempts. You can distinguish interfaces by mac-address  and/or by device-name, but you will have to adjust the script for each computer you want to run it on.

Comment: Tonny that's what I was afraid of. It's a shame since it ruins my script idea. Just so I know for my own purposes, is there third party software that can track "most recent mac address inserted" type data so it can be used in a script?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this batch file that execute a powershell command can help you or not ?

Just give a try and tell me if this what you want or you want something else ?

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Get MAC Address
Powershell "Get-NetAdapter | ? status -eq 'up' | select InterfaceDescription,Name,MacAddress | clip | notepad;Sleep -Seconds 1;Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^V')"
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Comment: This is very interesting thanks! On my phone now but will be at my PC in a few hours. To simplify, I'm really looking for a script that will copy the MAC of the last networking device inserted in my computer. Is this even possible??

Comment: It's a nice script but I found that as Tonny stated, there's no way to pull data from Windows that it doesn't keep track of in the first place. Sigh. I wasted too many hours on this silly idea.